# Проблемы с запуском старой программы на новой машине

Tags: runtime

Есть старая программа, она запускается под DOSBOX, но хотелось бы, чтобы она запускалась и без него. Но есть ошибка Runtime error 200 at XXXX:YYYY связанная со скоростью процессора, то есть она возникает только при переходе на более быстрые процессоры. Как ее исправить, чтобы приложение стало доступно всегда?

Comment: Если есть исходник - очень просто... Иначе - проще с нуля сделать... p.s. Если речь не о какой либо молотилке данных, а о графике\музыке - забудьте.

Comment: там программа для прибора старого

Comment: Остальное вы решили проигнорировать?)) Исходник есть? Документация? Документация на прибор?

Comment: если бы был исходник я бы не спрашивал) документации тоже никакой нет

Comment: Тогда ваше дело боль, дизасемблер и вытаскивание алгоритма взаимодействия с железкой, а потом воспроизведение "софта" под современное железо =)

Comment: Я читал это вроде как-то патчами лечится

Comment: А если так в лоб искать, то где возможна сама ошибка? Я читал, что это ошибка деления на ноль, но самой процедуры деления я не нашёл. Или вы имели ввиду разбираться в коде и все с нуля переписывать?

Comment: Да, можно патчами полечить, чтобы их разработать надо `дизасемблер и вытаскивание алгоритма взаимодействия с железкой,` а потом `разработка патча` что по трудозатратам может быть намного больше чем `воспроизведение "софта" под современное железо`

Comment: Где угодно в пределах исходной программы...

Comment: Под воспроизведением софта имеется ввиду переписанная программа или исправленная эта?

Comment: Переписаная, обычно, когда нет очень спецефической молотилки данных с кучей формул, проще сделать с нуля зная как оно работало

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, попробуем